# Java generic/wildcard type mismatch

Tags: java, generics, types, lambda

I'm trying to build a Java event emitter, which would have a list of callbacks (implementing Consumer interface) mapped with an event name.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.EventObject;

public class Emitter
{
    protected HashMap<String, PriorityQueue<Consumer<? extends EventObject>>> listeners;

    public Emitter()
    {
        this.listeners = new HashMap<String, PriorityQueue<Consumer<? extends EventObject>>>();
    }

    public Emitter on(String eventName, Consumer<? extends EventObject> listener)
    {
        if (!this.listeners.containsKey(eventName)) {
            this.listeners.put(eventName, new PriorityQueue<Consumer<? extends EventObject>>());
        }

        this.listeners.get(eventName).add(listener);

        return this;
    }

    public <E extends EventObject> Emitter emit(E event)
    {
        String eventName = event.getClass().getName();

        for (Consumer<? extends EventObject> listener : this.listeners.get(eventName)) {
            listener.accept(event);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

I get this compile error:

```
Emitter.java:31: error: incompatible types: E cannot be converted to CAP#1
            listener.accept(event);
                            ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends EventObject declared in method <E>emit(E)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends EventObject from capture of ? extends EventObject
```

but the captured type  is clearly a subtype of , so it should work (but I understand I'm missing something).

The use should be something like this (where OpenEvent and CloseEvent extend EventObject of course):

```java
Emitter em = new Emitter();
em.on("open", (OpenEvent e) -> e.doOpen());
em.on("close", (CloseEvent e) -> e.doClose());
em.emit(new OpenEvent());
em.emit(new CloseEvent());
```

I suppose it's possible to do this type-safe, since I can specify the type of the consumer's object via lambda function. But how?

Answer (score 3):

That happens because `listener` is of type: `Consumer<? extends EventObject>` (so, it's a `Consumer` of some specific, but unknown type that extends `EventObject`), but you want it to accept an event of type `E`. The compiler cannot check if the unknown type indicated by the wildcard is equal to the type `E`.

Why are you using wildcards at all? It would be better to get rid of them, and do something like this:

```
public class Emitter<E extends EventObject>
{
    protected HashMap<String, PriorityQueue<Consumer<E>>> listeners;

    public Emitter()
    {
        this.listeners = new HashMap<String, PriorityQueue<Consumer<E>>>();
    }

    public Emitter on(String eventName, Consumer<E> listener)
    {
        if (!this.listeners.containsKey(eventName)) {
            this.listeners.put(eventName, new PriorityQueue<Consumer<E>>());
        }

        this.listeners.get(eventName).add(listener);

        return this;
    }

    public Emitter emit(E event)
    {
        String eventName = event.getClass().getName();

        for (Consumer<E> listener : this.listeners.get(eventName)) {
            listener.accept(event);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Note: A wildcard type with a `? extends EventObject` does *not* mean you can pass any object to it that extends `EventObject`; it specifies one specific, but unknown type that extends `EventObject`. Because what the exact type is, is unknown, this limits what you can do with it.

Comment: But then `Emitter` would not be a heterogenous container right?

Comment: Would this bind an Emitter instance to a single EventObject subtype? I'm trying to make an Emitter instance able to listen on different subtypes of EventObject, since I only use specific subtype methods inside the lambda function which is defined with the correct subtype as the argument.

Comment: No, then `Emitter` would not be a heterogenous container, and it would indeed bind `Emitter` to a single `EventObject` subtype. I don't think  it is possible in a way that is completely type-safe, without casts.

Comment: Then please show me (us) a way to do it with a heterogeneous container and those non-type-safe casts. I really need this.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus You could remove the type parameter `E` from `Emitter`, use `Consumer<EventObject>` instead of `Consumer<E>`, and then in places where you need to work with the `EventObject`, check what actual type it is with `instanceof` and cast it to that actual type.

Comment: That won't work, because I can't `listeners.add(new MyObject())` when `MyObject` is generic in itself.